# How to print sheet index content?

Tags: python, excel, xls

My code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("/home/jh/Downloads/N9140US2m.xls")
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
sheet_by_index = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)
print('Sheet Index', sheet_by_index)
```

Output

```
Sheet Names ['Contents', 'Data 1']
Sheet Index <xlrd.sheet.Sheet object at 0x7fb004611240>
```

I want to print sheet object.
This is how xls file looks like
[image]

If I go for solution that Ashinish suggested

```
print("{0} {1} {2}".format(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols))
```

than output is

```
Contents 15 6
```

EDIT

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("/home/milenko/Downloads/N9140US2m.xls")
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
sheet_by_index = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
second_column = sheet_by_index.col_values(1, start_rowx=3)
print('Second column', second_column)
```

Output

```
Second column ['', 'Click worksheet name or tab at bottom for data', 'Worksheet Name', 'Data 1', '', 'Release Date:', 'Next Release Date:', 'Excel File Name:', 'Available from Web Page:', 'Source:', 'For Help, Contact:', '']
```

Comment: Did you check the [README of xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)? `print("{0} {1} {2}".format(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols))` where `sh` is your `sheet_by_index`

Comment: I have two columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "sheet object"? What inside the sheet do you need printed?

Comment: Sheet index,values from second column.

Comment: You can iterate over the cells in the sheet as stated in the docs - `print("Cell B4 is {0}".format(sh.cell_value(rowx=4, colx=2)))`

Comment: Are you looking for all the contents of second column?

Comment: Yes,the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the contents of second column, use `col_values` :

```
second_column = sheet_by_index.col_values(1, start_rowx=3)
```

First parameter specifies which column starting from `0`. So `1` will be the second column.

The second parameter `start_rowx` specifies the starting row from which contents need to be read out. `start_rowx=3` means starting from row `4` (because, I find real values of your sheet starts from row `4`).

Comment: This should have worked. Make sure you have given path to the right `xls` file or then try printing each value by iterating through `second_column`.